# Searching with multiple keys and "begins with"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What's the best way to perform the following type of search in a collection named "things":

```
 mylist = ['lak', 'dodg', 'ang']
```

and the return could be:

```
 ["lake", "Lakers", "laky", "dodge", "Dodgers", "Angels", "angle"]
```

Would I need to perform a separate query for each?

Comment: Where do the "stems" like lak come from? Are they actual word stems like in a text search algorithm? If so, you should check out [text indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/). Otherwise, I do agree with the answer below, except I want to add that it would be nice not to have to do case insensitive because then MongoDB can optimize the query so it's not actually a regex query. Could you insert all of your words in lower case and search with lower case "stems"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you want to use the mongodb command `$in` to search for all things that match with something in your array.

The command you would use would be:

```
db.things.find( {name: { $in: mylist }} )
```

But for this to work you want to be using regular expressions in your array, so you can either define them in the array, or if you want to maintain strings then the best thing to do it probably just create another array and loop through and create regex from the strings.

```
mylist = [/^lak/i, /^dodg/i, /^ang/i]
```

The `^` making it match only if it begins with the value, and the `i` at the end to make the search case insensitive.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have updated my answer to make the regex case insensitive, and I have tested it on my local server and $in works fine with regex. You may be thinking of $all which doesn't work?

Comment: Hmm. I should read the documentation properly, [regex's are supported](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-with-a-regular-expression). But it should also have an anchor otherwise it could match "Sangria" for example. But maybe a word boundary would do.